# Using mod_proxy_cluster and mod_proxy in one VirtualHost of Apache (httpd) configuration

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, mod-proxy, mod-cluster, mod-proxy-balancer

I had the environment with several JBoss and Tomcat servers. They are connected to Apache via modcluster modules (to Apache IP address and port 8090). The Apache contains the configuration:

loadbalancer.conf

```
LoadModule slotmem_module modules/mod_slotmem.so
LoadModule manager_module modules/mod_manager.so
LoadModule proxy_cluster_module modules/mod_proxy_cluster.so
LoadModule advertise_module modules/mod_advertise.so

Listen *:8090
<VirtualHost *:8090>

 <Location /mod_cluster_manager>
    SetHandler mod_cluster-manager
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from 8.8.8.8
    Allow from all
  </Location>

  KeepAliveTimeout 60
  MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
  EnableMCPMReceive
  ManagerBalancerName My_Cluster
  AdvertiseFrequency 5

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/ca.key

ProxyPass /other_app http://192.168.100.70:8080/other_app
ProxyPassReverse /other_app http://192.168.100.70:8080/other_app

ProxyPass / balancer://My_Cluster

</VirtualHost>
```

All work ok but one new application doesn't support connection to Apache. I need to use ProxyPass. When I insterted the ProxyPass to 443 virtual host so all balanced contexts stopped to work. When I inserted:
ProxyPass / balancer://My_Cluster
The /other_app context stopped work.

Can you advise me how configure context /other_app handling by ProxyPass and all other contexes by modcluster balancer?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following top level directive (add just below the LoadModule's)

```
#This is needed to prevent mod_cluster creating balancer for all VH's
CreateBalancers 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do it with the following:

```
ProxyPass /other_app http://192.168.100.70:8080/other_app
ProxyPassReverse /other_app http://192.168.100.70:8080/other_app
ProxyPass /other_app !

ProxyPass / balancer://My_Cluster
```

Inspired by https://serverfault.com/questions/363788/serve-all-requests-via-proxy-except-a-specific-one